# workflow actions order of execution?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, ordering

I came to the scenario that randomly and on very few cases, some workflow actions are not executed sequentially. Example below:

Action 1 (change field X value)

Action 2 (create item on another list)

Action 3 (Wait for a field Y value to be changed on the current list)

The issue I have is that Action 3 has been executed and the workflow is in waiting status for days now, but the first 2 actions were never executed. Does anyone know how (order) the instructions are executed and if sequential order can be forced?

I was thinking that the blocs/steps might have an impact, like the block/step may ensure the actions inside are committed before entering the next block, but it is very difficult to test as the issue does not appear very often.

Could someone throw some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that is not happening any mistake in previous actions.

It may happen (has happened to me) an action fail and look like it was simply ignored. Place logs on them before and after running for you map where execution is occurring.

Comment: Definitely using a logging system is recommended here. Here is a link to a good article on it: http://dave-sampson.blogspot.ca/2012/06/simple-sharepoint-2010-workflow-error.html

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but as I said it is an issue that doesn't happen very often (like once every 2 months), so if I restart the workflow it will work fine, I know it for a fact as I had it before.

Comment: I found a possible workaround, to avoid it in the future, but I don't like it at all, which is adding a Pause for 1 minute after every activity as it theoretically forces to commit the pending activities.

Comment: Do you have 1 single workflow running on the item?

Comment: Maybe the first two steps failed for some reason? Use WriteTo Workflow History activity to keep track of execution order. But the order is sequential there is no doubt about that. You are facing a strange behavior...